# PostSharp get_Property error

Tags: c#, dictionary, telerik, postsharp, radgridview

I am using PostSharp and RadGridView from Telerik. Some columns have custom data using a DataTypeConverter, which I am using to load a value from a property named `Name` of type `AdvisableDictionary<Tkey, TValue>`.

The grid has the filter button and when clicked will show a popup window with Excel-like filtering options.

However when I click this button, I get an error saying `Failed to compare two elements in the array.` This happens only for the columns with this type of data. I don't have much experience with PostSharp, but I think this is generated by PostSharp.

Here are the last lines from Output window from PostSharp, before it throws the exception:

```
The thread 0x3964 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The thread 0x364 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'TranslatableObject.get_Name'

Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'TranslatableObject.<Name>c__Binding1.GetValue'

Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'TranslatableObject.<Name>c__Binding1.get_LocationInfo'

Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'TranslatableObject.<Name>c__Binding.GetValue'
```

what can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Could you please paste here the stack trace and full message of the exception? If you share a minimal example which reproduces this behavior, it would also help to identify the cause.

Comment: Thanks! [Here](http://www.telerik.com/account/ClientsFiles/2e7a5d04-c0cc-4c2f-a835-8531ead667c4_ExcelLikeFiltering.zip?accesskey=76010F0054C6AF950F4458F5A0E88AD6643EF13E&expires=636369830483897924) is a sample project. I found a solution like in answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out a solution: `AdvisableDctionary` does not implement IComparable used to sort the list of items.

I created a class to inherit `AdvisableDictionary` and implement `IComparable` and in `FilterConfirmed` event of the Filter Popup.

I corrected the value of the filter descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

You can created a class to inherit AdvisableDictionary and implement IComparable.

```
public class AdvisableDictionary: IComparable
{
    //here add the code from your heart
}
```

[HERE 1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33786/DataGridView-Filter-Popup)

[HERE 2](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_patterns_collections_advisabledictionary_2)

So its simple in FilterConfirmed event of the FilterPopup you need to correct the value of the filter descriptor.

That's it.

Here is a sample [prj](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/filtering/excel-like-filtering). Please take a look. Have fun enjoy the c# programming.

That it's my solution, need to try, to be a boss, to try hard, to be happy :)